# How to use initWithModulus function in MyCrypto library?

Tags: iphone, cryptography

I use MyCrypto library for a IPhone app.  The program will comunicate with a web service that is writen by WCF.The service will provide a public key by providing modulus and exponent. Thus, we need use initWithModulus to create a public key. The code is as following.

```
MYPrivateKey *pair = [[MYKeychain defaultKeychain] generateRSAKeyPairOfSize: 2048];
MYPublicKey *pub = pair.publicKey;
NSData * outModulus;
unsigned outExponent;
[pub getModulus:&outModulus exponent:&outExponent]; 
MYPublicKey *serverKey = [[MYPublicKey alloc] initWithModulus: outModulus exponent: outExponent]; 
NSString *tmpStr = @"test!"; 
NSData *tmpData = [tmpStr dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
NSData *crypted = [serverKey rawEncryptData: tmpData]; 
NSData *crypted2 = [pub rawEncryptData: tmpData];
```

For test, I use initWithModulus to create a publickey. Then the same data are encrypted with the original key and the new one.  But the lengths of the two encrypted data are different. How shoud I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the mismatched lengths? When I run this code (in the iOS 4 simulator) it works, and the length of the encrypted data is 256 bytes.

If you try encrypting with the original private key and then decrypting with the reconstituted public key, does that work?

Comment: Hi Alfke, Thank you for your response. The length of first one data is 172 bytes. Second one is 256 bytes. The decrypting result from the first one is not correct. The second one is right. My OS is Chinese version. Does it matter?